# What is the advantage of access token refresh token system?

Tags: security, access-token, refresh-token

I don't see why the access token-refresh token system is more secure. Can't I just stick to using an access token for like 5 days? It feels like there's not much of an advantage. If someone steals my access token in a system with access token-refresh token, I might end up in an equally or even worse situation, as the refresh token can stay active for a whole year. Hackers could just keep asking for new access tokens.

and other stuff like token-binding can be just done with the long lived access token...

I've been looking for answers, but no luck so far.
I hope to get a good answer here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The point is access separation. The access token and refresh token should have different storage and access, because if they don't, then you are right they make a lot less sense (see below).

In practice this means the access token can be stored by javascript in say localstorage, where it is susceptible to XSS attacks. However, the refresh token should then be set for a different domain, for the identity provider, maybe in a httponly cookie, because the app doesn't typically need to ever read it. This way an attacker that compromised the website via eg. XSS will not be able to access or use the refresh token, as that is set for the identity provider origin (and the same origin policy in the browser will prevent access).

If the access and refresh tokens are stored the same way, with the same access (eg. both in localstorage), then there is hardly any benefit. True, the shorter lived access token is sent with every request, while the refresh token is not, but a secure transport (TLS in https) prevents most threats while in transit anyway, so unless you have very specific threats that you want to mitigate, this is not a huge benefit of a separate refresh token.

Comment: so if I store my access token with a long expiration time (suppose it has 7 days to expire) securely, then I should be pretty safe right?

Comment: That is not the best practice, and will be a finding in penetration tests. It also depends on where you store it, localstorage is a definite weakness for this, but secure storage in a mobile app is more ok. Also if you stored a refresh token the same way, that wouldn't add much security.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused, suppose a hacker got a hold on my access token, and kept sending requests for newer access tokens, how am does it more secure than a long lived access token without a refresh token... Cant they just keep imitating me?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is.. it's not. If you store and access the two tokens the same way, they don't make a lot of sense. Still it's not a good practice to use long access tokens, but only adding a refresh token that is stored and accessed the same way (like both in localstorage) doesn't make it much more secure. If you stored them differently, then yes, for example the access token can be is localstorage, while the refresh token is a httponly cookie, then it's already better. If the domain for the refresh token is different, then it's getting pretty good.